# Unable to control drag button into a SecondViewController

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Screenshot]

As the title states, I am unable to control-drag a button into a SecondViewController that I created.

Here are all the steps that I took:

1) Went to Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller to create a new navigation controller. Then, I added a button on to my ViewController that links to another page.

2) I then created another swift file, SecondViewController.swift

3) I added a button to the "RootViewController" (which is basically what my original page is connected to)

4) I changed the class of the button to SecondViewController, and the class of "RootViewController" to SecondViewController.

5) I tried control-dragging the button from "RootViewController" into "SecondViewController", but it doesn't work.

Can anyone point out an error in the above 5 steps I took?

Answer (score 0):

A button is not a view controller. Its identity should remain `UIButton` or a subclass of `UIButton`.

Your VC entitled "Root View Controller" is an instance of UITableViewController. If you want to change its identity, you must subclass UITableViewController, and implement your table delegate and datasource methods within.

It is very misleading to call this subclass 'SecondViewController'. At least all it 'MyTableViewController'.

Then create *another* subclass, this time of `UIViewController`. Call it `MyDestinationViewController`. Drag out a VC to the right of the table VC, and change its identity in StoryBoard. Segue from the Table View cell prototype, revealed from the Scene hierarchy, to this destination controller.  (You need to use the Scene hierarchy because it's very inconvenient to select the correct level of the object hierarchy within Storyboard proper.)

Comment: I changed this, and it still doesn't work. Anything else that you see is wrong?

Comment: The layout is: non-subclassed UINavigationContrller -> "contains" Relationship -> RootViewController -> "show" segue -> SecondViewController, correct? Why did you feel you needed to change the Identity of the root view controller from 'RootViewController' to 'SecondViewController'?

Comment: SecondViewController.swift is a file - it is where I will display the button. Therefore, I should change the class of RootViewController, no?

Comment: Is RootViewController the name of your class, which your notation implies? In other words is there a RootViewController.swift file? Or is it just your informal, strange name for "the first descendant of the my navigation controller"? Is there *another* .swift file which is the destination VC of your segue? What name does that have? Your step 5 isn't making sense to me. Can you post a StoryBoard image?

Comment: Oh you didn't mention the Button is actually a subview of a prototype cell in a `UITableViewController`. (Question-asking skills...) Reveal the Scene hierarchy. Expand the Table view until you find the cell in there. From there, control-drag your segue from the *cell* (UITableViewCell) to the destination VC. BTW your screen capture shows no such destination VC. Still not making sense.